# tool to auto-format R code

Tags: r, formatting, autoformatting

Is there any tool (editor, script, whatever...) available that can automatically reformat R code? It does not need to be customizable but it must be able to recognize statements separated by either semicolons or newlines since this code has both. If it can put all statements on a separate line, consistently indent code blocks and consistently place braces I will be very happy.

**Edit: summarizing findings**

Thanks for the great answers. Here is what I've found.

- Both ESS and StatET are great R editors and do a nice job of auto indenting blocks of code. StatET allows you to select-all and re-indent everything in a file at once. From what I could tell ESS allows you to indent an entire function def at once but not the entire file (please correct me if I missed it). Neither of these will fix brace placement or break up multi-statement lines. (Eg: i = n*b;a=i+1)
- formatR is awesome. In addition to fixing indentation it will also place braces consistently and split up multi-statement lines.

Here's a little function I wrote so that I can convert an entire source dir (using the same underlying function as formatR which is strangely in the animation package).

```
library("animation")

tidy.all <- function(inDir = NULL, outDir = NULL, ...) {
    if (is.null(inDir) || is.na(outDir)) 
        stop("inDir can't be null or NA")
    if (!file.info(inDir)$isdir) 
        stop("inDir must be a directory")

    if (is.null(outDir) || is.na(outDir)) 
        stop("outDir can't be null or NA")
    if (!file.exists(outDir)) 
        dir.create(outDir)
    if (!file.info(outDir)$isdir) 
        stop("outDir must be a directory")

    for (f in dir(inDir)) {
        currFile <- file.path(inDir, f)
        if (length(grep(".*\\.R$", currFile, perl = T))) {
            outFile <- file.path(outDir, f)
            if (file.exists(outFile)) 
                stop(paste("refusing to overwrite", outFile))

            tidy.source(currFile, file = outFile, ...)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I write "pretty code" from the start because I find it easier to read. I use StatET plugin for Eclipse (I have tried ESS but I find it comparable to StatET) which is perfectly satisfactory for my line of work.

Comment: @romunov yes, I agree but most of the R code that I have to modify was not initially created by me

Comment: Keith, good point. In that case, I find formatR like an excellent option (as you've already discovered).

Comment: JGR also does code reformating

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although ESS is a much better long-term solution, if you just have a quick formatting job, perhaps this package will help: http://yihui.name/en/?s=formatr.

Answer (score 7):

Emacs with ESS does it *exceedingly well* -- and the default settings as recommended by R Core are in [Section 7 *R coding standards*](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#R-coding-standards) of the [R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html) manual.

Comment: How do you do it in ess?

Comment: Great. These are about set code styles. If the code is somewhat messy, is there a command to clean the format up?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, ESS only handles indenting, not other coding style issues like which line braces go on, how many spaces before a comment symbol, whether to put spaces around operators, whether to use `=` or `<-`, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

I use [StatET](http://www.walware.de/it/statet/), and it works quite well for this.

You could also try [the formatR package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formatR/index.html) on CRAN.

Comment: How do you do it in StatET, please? I couldn't find the option for it.

Answer (score 2):

Though I've never used it, perhaps the following eclipse plug-in  http://www.walware.de/it/statet/ might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ctrl + I in statET to fix the indent of your code.
However it is possible to use formatR package with code snippets that generate better result especially by assigning a hot key to it.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. 
There is a really EASY way for reformatting in R Studio : 
Just copy all your code and paste in a new `R script`