# Auto-format R code in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, autoformatting

Is there any possibilities for auto-formatting code in RStudio?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017877/tool-to-auto-format-r-code), but it is not connected with RStudio.

Also it is desirable that it be customizable formatting.

Answer (score 93):

**update: June-22-2018**

Thank you @Lorenz@kirill@yuhi for `styler` [package](http://styler.r-lib.org/index.html). I have used it for a while. The simplest after installation of the package is to just use

scroll to `Addin --> style active file`

Customization options via interface would give some control on styling we prefer.

Rstudio can now format code to look neat. Select the lines of interest and then navigate to `Code` >> `Reformat code` or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

or  just run the style directory command to style all the files in the directory.

```
styler::style_dir()
```

***update***:
This is a good way to re-structure the code, but it breaks at `,` for the elements of a vector. For few this is OK, but with many elements passed to a vector, it is overkill:

```
x <- c(
  "p.G12C",
  "p.F121S",
  "p.P124S",
  "p.P124L",
  "p.E13D",
  "p.E203K",
  "p.Q209P",
  "p.Q209P",
  "p.Q209L"
)
```

***Update: R-Studio Version 0.99.893***

There is a new feature that has been added by R-studio `Addins`. Part of this addins, now you can add @yuhi formatR as an Addin. This is more tidy and cleaner way to structure code than the built-in `code >> Refromat code`. However, the drawback with the Addin `Reformat R Code` it throws an error for Rshiny codes.

Answer (score 81):

First <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

If on a Mac, use <kbd>⌘</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

Comment: The best answer here.

Comment: How does this one work? Is there some way to configure this so that it runs on save or something like that?

Answer (score 37):

Go to the `Code` menu and select

> Reindent Lines

Under my OS, this has the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: Of course there is a shortcut, I have been using "Cut" and "Paste" to reformat...

Answer (score 33):

The package [styler](http://styler.r-lib.org) can format R code and you can access it via a RStudio Addin that allows formatting the active file, the highlighted code, the package and more. A distinguishing feature is its flexibility, as the transformation of code according to a style guide is done separately from specifying the style guide. This allows styling according to arbitrary style guide. As of version 1.2.0, this also holds for the Addin.

We've implemented the [tidyverse style guide](http://style.tidyverse.org) while allowing for quite some flexibility in styling. Also, the pipe, tidyeval syntax and more is handled properly. You can read an introduction in this [blog post](https://lorenzwalthert.github.io/stylerpost/).

If you don't want to follow the tidyverse style guide, you can have a look at the vignette ['Customizing Styler'](http://styler.r-lib.org/articles/customizing_styler.html) that describes how you can implement an arbitrary style guide. In this vignette, I show how you can implement a style guide consisting of one rule: Always break the line before `{`. Hope that helps.

Disclosure: I am the maintainer of styler.

Answer (score 16):

Use the [formatR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formatR/index.html) library (see [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formatR/formatR.pdf)):

```
install.packages("formatR")
    
library("formatR")
    
tidy_eval("filename.R")
```

Comment: `{formatR}` compared to `{styler}` is faster but cannot parse all code, sometimes drops comments, handles `%>%` and `!!(!)` unexpectedly and a few other things, summarised here: https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/558#issuecomment-542883365

Answer (score 7):

To add to the great answers that were already given: You can use the `styler` package in combination with the [shrtcts](https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/shrtcts/) package to enable **Format on Save** which is [still not officially supported by RStudio](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2563).

1. Use the command `shrtcts::edit_shortcuts()` in the RStudio Console to open the file where you define your custom shortcuts.
2. Paste the following code inside that file (set your preferred keybinding in the `@shortcut` line).

   ```
   #' Format on Save
   #'
   #' @description
   #'   Format Document with styler Package and Save Document.
   #' @interactive
   #' @shortcut Cmd+S
   function() {
     # format only .R and .Rmd files, but save all file types
     file_type <- tools::file_ext(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)

     if (file_type %in% c("R", "Rmd", "qmd")) {
       styler:::style_active_file() |>
         capture.output() |>
         invisible()
     }

     rstudioapi::documentSave() |>
       capture.output() |>
       invisible()
   }
   ```

   This solution uses the native pipe `|>` and thus requires `R 4.1`.
   You can of course just define separate variables in each line or use the     `magrittr` pipe if you use earlier versions of `R`.
3. Use the command `shrtcts::add_rstudio_shortcuts(set_keyboard_shortcuts = TRUE)` in the RStudio Console to add the new shortcut with its assigned keybinding. Then restart RStudio.

With this configuration pressing `Cmd+S` formats the active `.R` or `.Rmd` document with the `styler` package and saves the formatted version afterwards.
Files of all other types are saved without formatting, but you could easily extend the code above with a package that formats e.g. `.md` or `.py` files as well.

There exist cases where this approach code does *not* have the desired effect, for instance it does not work for new `Untitled` files or when your current `R` session is busy.

Comment: The function you wrote is very neat. I first overlooked that it is `cmd+S` and not `Ctrl+S` and took me a while to figure why it would not work. Thanks alot

Comment: This is great! One of my most missed features in RStudio.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I've been wanting. The only issue I can see is if there is a syntax error in the R code, the styling wont work and the file won't save.