# readable code lines R

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a shortcut to add a new line into the R (RStudio) code?

I would like to avoid something like `gapminder%>%filter(continent=="Asia")%>%group_by(year)%>%summarise(mean_pop=mean(pop))%>%ggplot(aes(x=year,y=mean_pop))+geom_point()+geom_line()+theme_bw()`

by using

```
gapminder %>%
   filter(continent == "Asia") %>%
   group_by(year) %>%
   summarise(mean_pop = mean(pop)) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = year, y = mean_pop)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_line() +
     theme_bw()
```

but without holding the space bar all the time..  and I googled now nearly half an hour and just didn't find a shortcut. Can't believe it?!
So how all are doing this?

Comment: What are you typing your R code into? RStudio? Emacs? Word? The plain old WIndows R.exe editor?

Comment: Are you using RStudio?

Comment: Yes, RStudio. Sorry!

Comment: see here [Auto-format R code in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703553/auto-format-r-code-in-rstudio)

Comment: Don't use space bar to indent your code btw. Use tab key.

Comment: @sera Thank you! So it is ctrl+shift+A? But there's nothing happening in my code..

Comment: @Ben see my answer. hope it helps

Comment: I’m not sure why you’re writing code as shown in the first instance. Just write it like you want it: Rstudio will even automatically provide the right indentation when you press the ‹Return› key at the right point in your code. And don’t use ‹Space› repeatedly to manually indent the code to the right level: use the ‹Tab› key instead.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Return/Enter just executes the command. How shall this help me formatting?

Comment: @Ben Ah. You should be entering the code in the *code editor*, not directly in the console.

Comment: Aaaah..  there's a separate code frame..    can't believe it again..    thanks a lot! How do I accept your comment as a solution?

Comment: @Ben Wait, I’ll write it as an answer. ;-) Then you can accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RStudio has separate windows for editing code and executing commands:

[image]

In this case, the top left is the code editor (but the layout is modifiable). Below is the console.

To edit code, create a new file or open an existing file, and edit it in the code editor. RStudio will automatically attempt to format your code as appropriate when you hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

To execute code you’ve written in the code editor there are several choices. To execute just the current statement, you can hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>. There are more options directly above the code editor (check out the menus ‹Run› and ‹Source›).

Answer (score 0):

In your case try to use `;` and not `%>%`.

**Example**:

```
gapminder;filter(continent=="Asia");group_by(year);summarise(mean_pop=mean(pop))
```

Press **CTRL + SHIFT + A** or **select all** code and go to **Code-> Reformat code**

**Result**:

```
gapminder
filter(continent == "Asia")
group_by(year)
summarise(mean_pop = mean(pop))
```

Comment: At first thanks! In "Code" I have only "Go To File/Function", "Show Diagnostics" and "Source File". Where is "Reformat code"? The keyboard shortcut does not work.

Comment: No, that’s almost certainly not what OP wants; not sure why it’s upvoted.

Comment: @Ben type: version. What version do you have? I have  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)

Comment: @sera I have RStudio 1.0.143?

Comment: I think it's quite inefficient + wrong since the pipe operator have disapeared (so the code won't work now and the OP has to put the pipe for each line where it's missing). What the OP should do is to learn how to use properly how to indent his code with tab key and return.

Comment: @MbrMbr Tab pop ups suggestions of which function I might want to use. And return executes the command line. I'm a little bit lost..

Comment: @Ben Are you sure you're not running the lines in the console instead of the editor ?