# Auto-format javascript code in RStudio Server

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, rstudio

In RStudio it´s possible to autoformat R Code with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (e.g. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703553/auto-format-r-code-in-rstudio/34856235)). Now my question is, how to autoformat javascript code in RStudio (e.g. if you are working on a shiny app).

Comment: Auto-formatting of JavaScript code has not yet been implemented in RStudio -- you could consider filing a [feature request](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues).

Answer (score 0):

The [prettifyAddins](https://github.com/stla/prettifyAddins) package I've just made provides two RStudio addins for JavaScript files and more: an addin which only reindents the code and an addin which prettifies the code, e.g. it adds semi-colons when they are missing. I will submit it to CRAN soon.

[image]

## Update

I updated `prettifyAddins`. It has now addins using the `V8` package, and Shiny is not used for these addins, the prettified code directly replaces the current code.

Another possibility is my (freshly built) package [aceEditor](https://github.com/stla/aceEditor/tree/main/inst). It opens the Ace editor in the viewer pane of RStudio:

[image]

This provides a second source editor in RStudio. And many languages are supported.

Comment: Thank you! Which R versions are supported ?

Comment: @Manuel The R version has no importance, but you need a not too old version of RStudio.