# Setting line length for reformatting code in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a way to make RStudio use a length of 100 or 120 per row when reformatting code? So far I can only make it show me where lines end. Is there - using Ubuntu here - some config file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an Addin/package that does exactly that. It's called `formatR`. You can see it in action [here on the right](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/).

Edit: In addition you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703553/auto-format-r-code-in-rstudio) for a more in depth overview.

Comment: @AltaStatistika please accept an answer if it answered your question. Thanks!

Comment: Immediately accepting an answer as the answer doesn't make sense. How should I having the question know it's the best one?

Comment: That is true. However, some beginners neglect to do it, and I needed the reputation to be able to comment. That's why I said it. :)