# Generating Formatted data.frame or tibble (or any function) Calls from Existing Data in R Script

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to create a reproducible and formatted call to data.frame or tibble in R, akin to manually constructing it. Given a data.frame named df:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1          5.1         3.5
2          4.9         3.0
3          4.7         3.2
4          4.6         3.1
```

I can use dput(df) to obtain an output like:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, I seek a way to generate the formatted call to data.frame (or tibble) as if I were constructing it manually with arguments separated row-wise:

```
data.frame(Sepal.Length = c(5.1,
                            4.9,
                            4.7,
                            4.6),
           Sepal.Width = c(3.5,
                           3,
                           3.2,
                           3.1)
           )
```

I wonder if there's an existing RStudio add-in or a straightforward method to achieve this. I have not found a satisfactory answer on Stack Overflow, and previous interactions with ChatGPT were unhelpful.

---

**subquestion 2**

###### Formatting Function Calls in RStudio for Better Readability

Is there a simple way within RStudio to obtain formatted function calls like:

```
function(
    argumentA,
    argumentB,
    argumentC
)
```

Instead of a single line:

```
function(argumentA, argumentB, argumentC)
```

I'm seeking a method to improve code readability by breaking down function arguments onto new lines, and I wonder if there's a built-in feature or add-in for achieving this in RStudio. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you can use the `construct` function from the `construct` package, which I believe outputs the exact thing you want. Here, on the full `iris` dataset:

```
library(constructive)

construct(iris)
```

Output:

```
data.frame(
  Sepal.Length = c(
    5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 5, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7,
    5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 5.4, 5.1, 4.6, 5.1, 4.8, 5, 5, 5.2, 5.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.4,
    5.2, 5.5, 4.9, 5, 5.5, 4.9, 4.4, 5.1, 5, 4.5, 4.4, 5, 5.1, 4.8, 5.1, 4.6, 5.3,
    5, 7, 6.4, 6.9, 5.5, 6.5, 5.7, 6.3, 4.9, 6.6, 5.2, 5, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 5.6, 6.7,
    5.6, 5.8, 6.2, 5.6, 5.9, 6.1, 6.3, 6.1, 6.4, 6.6, 6.8, 6.7, 6, 5.7, 5.5, 5.5,
    5.8, 6, 5.4, 6, 6.7, 6.3, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 6.1, 5.8, 5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.7, 6.2, 5.1,
    5.7, 6.3, 5.8, 7.1, 6.3, 6.5, 7.6, 4.9, 7.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.5, 6.4, 6.8, 5.7,
    5.8, 6.4, 6.5, 7.7, 7.7, 6, 6.9, 5.6, 7.7, 6.3, 6.7, 7.2, 6.2, 6.1, 6.4, 7.2,
    7.4, 7.9, 6.4, 6.3, 6.1, 7.7, 6.3, 6.4, 6, 6.9, 6.7, 6.9, 5.8, 6.8, 6.7, 6.7,
    6.3, 6.5, 6.2, 5.9
  ),
  Sepal.Width = c(
    3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3, 3, 4, 4.4, 3.9,
    3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.4, 3.2, 3.1, 3.4, 4.1,
    4.2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 2.3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8, 3, 3.8, 3.2, 3.7,
    3.3, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 2.3, 2.8, 2.8, 3.3, 2.4, 2.9, 2.7, 2, 3, 2.2, 2.9, 2.9,
    3.1, 3, 2.7, 2.2, 2.5, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4,
    2.7, 2.7, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3, 3, 2.5, 2.6, 3, 2.6, 2.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 2.9, 2.5,
    2.8, 3.3, 2.7, 3, 2.9, 3, 3, 2.5, 2.9, 2.5, 3.6, 3.2, 2.7, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2,
    3, 3.8, 2.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.8, 2.8, 2.7, 3.3, 3.2, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3, 2.8, 3.8, 2.8,
    2.8, 2.6, 3, 3.4, 3.1, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.4, 3
  ),
  Petal.Length = c(
    1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2,
    1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 1.5, 1, 1.7, 1.9, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6,
    1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 1.4,
    1.6, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 4.7, 4.5, 4.9, 4, 4.6, 4.5, 4.7, 3.3, 4.6, 3.9, 3.5, 4.2,
    4, 4.7, 3.6, 4.4, 4.5, 4.1, 4.5, 3.9, 4.8, 4, 4.9, 4.7, 4.3, 4.4, 4.8, 5, 4.5,
    3.5, 3.8, 3.7, 3.9, 5.1, 4.5, 4.5, 4.7, 4.4, 4.1, 4, 4.4, 4.6, 4, 3.3, 4.2,
    4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 3, 4.1, 6, 5.1, 5.9, 5.6, 5.8, 6.6, 4.5, 6.3, 5.8, 6.1, 5.1,
    5.3, 5.5, 5, 5.1, 5.3, 5.5, 6.7, 6.9, 5, 5.7, 4.9, 6.7, 4.9, 5.7, 6, 4.8, 4.9,
    5.6, 5.8, 6.1, 6.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.6, 5.5, 4.8, 5.4, 5.6, 5.1, 5.1,
    5.9, 5.7, 5.2, 5, 5.2, 5.4, 5.1
  ),
  Petal.Width = c(
    0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2,
    0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2,
    0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4,
    0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.3, 1.6, 1, 1.3, 1.4, 1,
    1.5, 1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 1.1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4,
    1.7, 1.5, 1, 1.1, 1, 1.2, 1.6, 1.5, 1.6, 1.5, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1,
    1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.3, 2.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8,
    2.5, 2, 1.9, 2.1, 2, 2.4, 2.3, 1.8, 2.2, 2.3, 1.5, 2.3, 2, 2, 1.8, 2.1, 1.8,
    1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 1.6, 1.9, 2, 2.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.3,
    1.9, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.9, 2, 2.3, 1.8
  ),
  Species = factor(rep(c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), each = 50L))
```

For part 2, in Rstudio if you highlight your code  `shift` + `control` + `A` it will properly reformat your code for you. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012908/12109788) for the Stack Overflow question/answer to this part)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(datapasta)
clipr::write_clip(df) # or select and Ctrl-C

#Addins -- DATAPASTA - Paste as tribble
tibble::tribble(
  ~Sepal.Length, ~Sepal.Width,
            5.1,          3.5,
            4.9,            3,
            4.7,          3.2,
            4.6,          3.1
  )

#Addins - DATAPASTA - Paste as data.frame
data.frame(
  Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6),
   Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1)
)
```

For your second question (which should be a second question), the `styler` package will do this, but you'd need to find a style with that rule, or create one.

Comment: thank you, Jon. I was not sure this should be a second question, as they are related, thanks for the clarifications and this excelent `datapasta` suggestion